# How to replace text in pipelined data without it converting the underlying object into a string object

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to replace text in pipelined data without it converting the underlying object into a string object?

I'm querying a dns server for hostname and ipaddresses with the following:

```
$DnsData = Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -NameSpace Root\MicrosoftDNS -ComputerName "DCName"  -Filter "DomainName = 'OurDomain.local'" `
        |?{$_.IPAddress -like "192.168.100.*" } | Select-Object -property Ownername, ipaddress
```

Which returns data like:

```
Ownername                               ipaddress
---------                               ---------
2UA0123AB0.OurDomain.local              192.168.100.101
2UA0123AB1.OurDomain.local              192.168.100.102
2UA0123AB2.OurDomain.local              192.168.100.103
2UA0123AB3.OurDomain.local              192.168.100.104
2UA0123AB4.OurDomain.local              192.168.100.106
```

I want to strip out the domain suffix (OurDomain.local), but if I put a replace step in the query such as:

```
$DnsData = (Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -NameSpace Root\MicrosoftDNS -ComputerName "DCName"  -Filter "DomainName = 'OurDomain.local'" `
    |?{$_.IPAddress -like "192.168.100.*" } | Select-Object -property Ownername, ipaddress) -replace ".OurDomain.local",""
```

or

```
$DnsData = Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -NameSpace Root\MicrosoftDNS -ComputerName "DCName"  -Filter "DomainName = 'OurDomain.local'" `
    |?{$_.IPAddress -like "192.168.100.*" } | Select-Object -property Ownername, ipaddress|foreach{$_ -replace ".OurDomain.local",""}
```

The data is returned as:

```
@{OwnerName=2UA0123AB0; ipaddress=192.168.100.101}
@{OwnerName=2UA0123AB1; ipaddress=192.168.100.102}
```

And as it's a string, I can't refer to the properties e.g. in a loop:

```
Foreach($pc in $DnsData)
{
    $pc.Ownername
}
```

How do I change the query to replace the text but without changing the objects? I've worked around it for now, but it bugs me that I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this isn't simple.

Try to add a property, containing the info you need, to the object:

```
$DnsData = Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -NameSpace Root\MicrosoftDNS -ComputerName "DCName" -Filter "DomainName = 'OurDomain.local'" |
    ? { $_.IPAddress -like "192.168.100.*" }

$DnsData | % { Add-Member -InputObject $_ Hostname ($_.Ownername -replace ".OurDomain.local", "") }
$DnsData | fl Hostname, IPaddress
```

Comment: This would get the job the done, though I'm still holding out for a solution that modifies the existing property rather than adding a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$DnsData = Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -NameSpace Root\MicrosoftDNS -ComputerName "DCName"  -Filter "DomainName = 'OurDomain.local'" `
    |?{$_.IPAddress -like "192.168.100.*" } | Select-Object @{Name="OwnerName";Expression={$_.ownername -replace ".OurDomain.local",""}}, ipaddress
```

Comment: I had tried that, but it just returns the OwnerName, not the IPAddress .

Comment: yea hmm it seems replace kind of takes the object out of the pipeline and just outputs the string value

Comment: @chris i thought a bit about it and i think i have a solution (see code above)